# Bootstrap: Need help to center a button

Tags: css, center

Im trying to center this button but can't seem to get it to work, any help is much appreciated.

```
<div class="cta-btn">
                                    <a class="btn btn-cta text-center" href="#" role="button">EXPLORE</a>
                            </div>
```

And the CSS

```
 .btn-cta{
   padding: 25px 80px;
   border: 3px solid white;
   background-color: transparent;
   color: white;
   font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 1.4em;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use class **text-center**

```
<div class="cta-btn text-center">
                                    <a class="btn btn-cta text-center" href="#" role="button">EXPLORE</a>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the `.text-center` class on the enclosing div

```
<div class="cta-btn text-center">
    <a class="btn btn-cta" href="#" role="button">EXPLORE</a>
</div>
```

Also, if you want the button to fill the width of the div, add the `.btn-block` class to the button.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `text-align: center;`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Jost, adding text-align: center to his CSS was my answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```